# How to get a "lack of criminal record" certificate from an Israeli consulate?

Tags: paperwork, israel, israeli-citizens

Assuming an Israeli citizen needs a "lack of criminal record" while abroad, how can they get one from their local consulate? The official websites are a bit confusing as to how the procedure works.

Comment: 1. What you're getting is a copy of your criminal record. It just happens to be empty (hopefully). 2. Did you try asking the consulate over email or phone how to get a copy of your record? 3. Sometimes what you need is to have them send a third-party a copy of your record, FYI.

Comment: Mine was a signed letter from a lawyer saying "I claim to have no criminal record of any kind..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've completed the process so now I can post my own answer.

First, you have to go to the local Israeli embassy/consulate and apply for an "absence of criminal records" certificate. To apply you need the following documents:

1. Israeli passport
2. Filled out [form](https://mfa.gov.il/MFA_Graphics/MFA%20Gallery/Consular%20forms/AbsenceCriminalRecord.pdf). I've only filled out the fields in English and the consulate employee filled-in the rest.
3. Address of the entity requesting the certificate. In my case it was the address of a local court.
4. Cash for paying the [Apostille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille_Convention) fee. It was 10 Euros at the embassy in Prague.
5. Address/phone of a local translator, assuming you need it in a language other than English/Hebrew. I didn't have it on hand, so I've sent them an email with the address later on.

The way the process works is as following:

1. You apply for the certificate.
2. After 3 weeks, the certificate arrives from Israel to the consulate.
3. If an English version is acceptable, the consulate will forward it to the address of the entity which requested the certificate.
4. If not, the consulate will forward it to the chosen translator.
5. The translator will translate the document into the language of your choosing and mail it to the final recipient. I've also requested the translator to attach an explanation letter so that the local court could quickly understand why they've received this document.

Overall it's a fairly straightforward process.